# Is there a way to make Vista recognize MIDI files?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, midi

I recently spent a couple of weekends trying to get a Vista machine to recognize MIDI files.  I spent time looking for workarounds or third-party programs to resolve this, but nothing I tried worked.  Not only will Vista not recognize MIDI files, but third-party programs that will normally play MIDI files (Winamp, for example) won't play them on a Vista machine.

Does anyone have a method to make a Vista system recognize MIDI files, or is this a lost cause?  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the midi file and open it with Windows Media Player. Typically this first part application will play midi files, however if that is not the case, it may be another issue that is not related to your environment rather than your applications.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can try is if you want winamp to recognize the files, uninstall, and re-install winamp. When it asks you what file types to register it with, make sure .mid is selected.